# Android emulator can't intercept SMS messages when app is closed

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android app with "Xamarin.Android" to intercept incoming SMS messages. When I deployed the app using the Visual Studio built-in emulator (Android 9 image), the SMS is not intercepted when the app is closed. But when I deployed the same app on Galaxy Note 8 (Android 9), it worked perfectly.

I dug up more details about the updates and changes in recent Android versions and how it handled background services and the limitations on implicit broadcast receivers. I found out that the SMS_RECEIVE is already exempted from any restrictions, so the broadcast should be delivered to my app, even when it is closed.

I rewrote the SMS Broadcast receiver part using Java to test it in Android Studio; it worked on the Android Studio emulator and device.

Is this a common issue in the Visual Studio emulator? Is there a configuration that I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the solution was only to update the built-in Android Emulator that was included with Visual Studio.

I was using an older version (28.0.25) that was released last March, while the new available version (29.2.1) released in September solved the issue with this simple update, although this issue was not highlighted in any of the release notes of the stable versions since march.